# The set of neighbors of a cluster?

Tags: notation

I am reading a paper on multi agent control and struggling a little bit with the notation introduced as I am not very familiar with graph theory. I did google my questions but that has been to no avail.

[image]
[image]

Specifically, I have two questions:

First what does E is a subset of V x V. What does the multiplication operator mean in this context.

Second, how do I interpret equation 1? What does it mean? The way I read that statement is
that the set Nj is the a subset of all the nodes such that vi is in J and that the edge between vi and vj is a in E. However, what does this mean and how is this different from the definition of Ni.

Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $X\times Y$ is the *cartesian product of sets*. In notation $$X\times Y =\{(x, y) \mid x\in X, y\in Y \}$$

For example $\Bbb R^2 =\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$

2. $N_J$ denotes the set of all points that are the in the neighbourhood of at least one node inside the cluster.